# Entering users into a MySQLi database

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a form that I want to use to enter users into a database. I used MySQLi with prepared statements. I want to make sure that I sanitized my data well.

```
<?php
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
require_once './db_con.php';
$id = '';
$firstname = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$lastname = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
//$val_email = trim(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
$password = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$password2 = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$errs = array();
#firstname
    if ( empty($firstname) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please enter your first name.";
    }

#lastname
    if ( empty($lastname) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please enter your last name.";
    }

#email
    if ( empty($email) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please enter your E-mail.";
    }
#email validation
    if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please enter a valid E-mail.";
    }
#check if email exist
    if ( email_exists($email,$connection) ) {
        $errs[] = "Your E-mail already exists.";
    }

#password    
    if ( empty($password) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please enter your password.";
    } elseif (strlen($password) < 6) {
        $errs[] = "Your password must have  at least 6 characters.";
}
#confirm-password    
    if ( empty($password2) ) {
        $errs[] = "Please confirm your password.";
    } else {
#matching-passwords        
        if ( $password !== $password2 ) {
            $errs[] = "Password didn't match.";
        }
    }

if ( !empty( $errs ) )  {
    foreach ($errs as $err) {
        echo $err.'</br >';
    }    
} else {

    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $id, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $hashed_password);
    if ( !($stmt->execute()) ) {
        echo "There was a problem, Try again.";
    } else {
        echo "You are registered now.";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
#functions
function email_exists($email,$connection) {

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rows_count = $result->num_rows;

    if ( $rows_count >= 1 ) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: This question [is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8895/31503)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is perfectly safe. The only issue with sanitization in this code is that it makes the data, so to say, *overly-sanitized*.

The way you are getting your input variables, makes them suitable for the HTML output. But there is no HTML output in the code present. Which makes such santitization slightly misplaced. It is considered a better practice to "sanitize"  the data right before use, instead of doing that prematurely.

The way you are doing it now could result in some undesired consequences.    For example, imagine a honest girl named Sarah O'Hara going to register with your site. Your code will make her name `"Sarah O&#039;Hara"` to be saved in the database. Next time she will try search for her name, a search for "Sarah O'Hara" will find nothing.

Therefore it is recommended to sanitize a variable just before the actual use. E.g. making it suitable for the HTML output right before the actual output. Given modern template engines such as [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) are doing an auto-escaping, it will take you no trouble having the user data properly sanitized.

In this regard I would get input variables without any HTML related sanitization, I.e.

```
$firstname = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname'));
$lastname = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname'));
```

whereas actual sanitization being done before the actual output.

Comment: -I want to make it clear since i used prepared statement, i don't need to sanitize my data, right?
-where in my code to use mysql_real_escape_string in my code?

Comment: Don't you mean `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? This is an 'or' problem: You either use prepared statements **or** you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, never both. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is used to escape special characters in a string for use in a SQL query. Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z. You don't use your data in a query string, you use a prepared statement. See the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: so i don't need to use any method to sanitize my data. really thanks for the help